# Add a hyperlink to each entry of a table from mysqli

Tags: php, url, html-table, genome

I'm trying to add a direct link to the genomic region of each gene on a table generated with mysqli data, but can't figure out the way. The idea is that every gene name has a hyperlink to it's region on a genome browser.

The problem comes when I have to generate the link dynamically for each gene depending on the gene selected by the user.

I've tried this:

```
echo '<td><a href="http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?"'.urlencode($genome.$row['name2'])'>'$row['name2']'</a></td>';
```

`$genome` is the par of the url specific for each species and assembly, and `$row['name2']` is the name of each gene.

Comment: And what is the problem ? any error ? (Be careful with your echo, there are mistakes. 1. You should separate **each** part by a separator (i.e. `,`) 2. You have a quote `"` before the dynamic code ... but the link is not complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had your quote double quote in wrong location if there are additional problems will need more info

```
    // Yours
echo '<td><a href="http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?"'.urlencode($genome.$row['name2'])'>'$row['name2']'</a></td>'
// Fixed Quote
echo '<td><a href="http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?'.urlencode($genome.$row['name2'])'">'$row['name2']'</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 2):

I complete my previous comment with some advice - maybe this is the answer to your question.

## 1. How to use echo

You should separate each part of the `echo` function by a separator.
The common separator is the coma `,`. Of course, you can also concatenate with a dot `.`

```
echo 'a', 'b', 'c', $var, 'con'ca' . 'tenated';
```

> Tips: use the coma only for `echo` instruction. It's faster :)

## 2. Issues on your code

If I take your generated output, you should have something like this - with **cho* corrections:

```
<td><a href="http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?"%20gen%20The+name>The name</a><td>
```

As you can see, the link is `http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?`. The content after the `"` is ignored.

> **Solution**: Move to the dynamic part of the link, at the correct place :)